# displaying a std::list<type*>

Tags: c++, stdlist

I have a little problem, because I'm making my school project and I need to create something like container witch is using std::list .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
class SomeContainer
{
    public:
        SomeContainer &operator[](size_t i) ;
        void push_back(const T &);
        std::list<T> someContent_;
}

class A
{
    //it doesn't matter whats inside
}

class B: public A
{}

class C: public A
{}

int main()
{
    SomeContainer <A*> something_;
    something_.push_back(new B);
    cout<< something [0];
}
```

I made something like this ,and there is a question. How can I display class A content, not the pointer to it? When I'm using int or string type everything works fine, but with `<A*>` even if I write

```
cout << *something[0];
```

It won't work.Thanks for help :)

Comment: What is the error you get? does cout << some_instance_of_A work? (i.e. did you implement the operator <<(ostream) for it?

Comment: Why does your `operator[]` return the container type and not what it contains?

Comment: You are doing *far* too much at once this early in your life. Write several *small*, *separate* programs that make you completely familiar first with a) `std::list<int>`, b) pointers and dereferencing, c) overloading `operator<<`. Only then come back to build something this complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator[]` has to have this signature:

```
T &operator[](size_t i);
T const& operator[](size_t i) const; // possibly const overload
```

You want it to return a reference to one element of type `T`, not a container. But you'll need to iterate through the `std::list`, use rather `std::vector` for random access.

Then, you'll be able to:

```
cout << *something[0];
```

(assuming you have `operator<<` for `A` overloaded).

Answer (score 1):

`A` must be "displayable" on `cout`, so your need to declare a `operator<<` for `A` objects:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
{
     os << "a A object"; // send A attributes to os.
     return os;
}
```

Also, make sure you send `A` object to the stream but not a pointer to it. As your container stores `A*`, `something[0]` is a pointer to `A` (`A*`), so you need to dereference it:

```
cout << *(something[0]);
```

Comment: (I got this the wrong way around on the other answer...) `*` has lower precedence than `[]`, so you could do without the `(parentheses)` here, but it doesn't hurt to explicitly show the order of evaluation. :)

Comment: Definitely, I prefere to use parenthesis rather than going to the standard and figure out what the priorities are.....